# How to resolve this (disagrees about version of symbol) for example for (journal_restart)?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, ext3

I try to modify Jbd Module.symvers and make versions of these functions of jbd the same as what is in /proc/kallsyms (for all symvers:ext3, root kernel directory and jbd), but when compiling it will be the same old value in jbd/Module.symvers (not seeable in jbd.mod.c). I've seen scripts/mod/modpost.c and there was no instance of those symbols (like journal_restart. I see a lot of disagree about version of .... and the next line this Unknown symbols... of that in disagree symbold in dmesg.

How can resolve this problem for example for (journal_restart)?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be me, but I have a hard time understanding this question. You might have more success if you rephrase it.

Comment: I mean error when using insmod

Comment: You did not compile the module for the correct kernel version/configuration.

Comment: I know, I've the best I could find, as it is not a standard version linux. I want to resolve this.